# How would you minimize or compress Core Data sqlite file size?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I have a 215MB csv file which I have parsed and stored in core data wrapped in my own custom objects. The problem is my core data sqlite file is around 260MB. The csv file contains about 4.5million lines of data on my city's transit system (bus stop, times, routes etc).

I have tried modifying attributes so that arrays of strings representing stop times are stored instead as NSData files but for some reason the file size still remains at around 260MB.

I can't ship an app this size. I doubt anyone would want to download a 260MB app even if it means they have the whole city's transit schedule on it.

Are there any ways to compress or minimize the storage space used (even if it means not using core data, I am willing to hear suggestions)?

**EDIT:** I just want to provide an update right now because I have been staring at the file size in disbelief. With some clever manipulation involving strings, indexing and database normalization in general, I have managed to reduce the size down to 6.5MB or 2.6MB when compressed. About 105,000 objects stored in Core Data containing the full details of the city's transit system. I'm almost in tears right now D':

Comment: I just saw your updated comment about your final size. Very impressive. 100:1 compression of real-world data should make anyone proud.

Comment: Very late but if you check out the app Transit, I've talked with them and they've managed to get 260MB down to just **800KB**

Answer (score 7):

Unless your original CSV is encoded in a really foolish manner, it seems unlikely that the  size is not going to get below 100M, no matter how much you compress it. That's still really large for an app. The solution is to move your data to a web service. You may want to download and cache significant parts, but if you're talking about millions of records, then fetching from a server seems best. Besides, I have to believe that from time to time the transit system changes, and it would be frustrating to have to upgrade a many-10s-of-MB app every time there was a single stop adjustment.

---

I've said that, but actually there are some things you may consider:

- Move booleans into a bit fields. You can put 64 booleans into an NSUInteger. (And don't use a full 64-bit integer if you just need 8 bits. Store the smallest thing you can.)
- Compress how you store times. There are only 1440 minutes in a day. You can store that in 2 bytes. Transit times are generally not to the second; they don't need a CGFloat.
- Days of the week and dates can similarly be compressed.
- Obviously you should normalize any strings. Look at the CSV for duplicated string values on many lines.
- I generally would recommend raw sqlite rather than core data for this kind of problem. Core Data is more about object persistence than raw data storage. The fact that you're seeing a 20% bloat over CSV (which is not itself highly efficient) is not a good direction for this problem.
- If you want to get even tighter, and don't need very good searching capabilities, you can create packed data blobs. I used to do this on phone switches where memory was extremely tight. You create a bit field struct and allocate 5 bits for one variable, and 7 bits for another, etc. With that, and some time shuffling things so they line up correctly on word boundaries, you can get pretty tight.

---

Since you care most about your initial download size, and may be willing to expand your data later for faster access, you can consider very domain-specific compression. For example, in the above discussion, I mentioned how to get down to 2 bytes for a time. You could probably get down to 1 bytes in many cases by storing times as delta minutes since the last time (since most of your times are going to be always increasing by fairly small steps if they're bus and train schedules). Abandoning the database, you could create a very tightly encoded data file that you could extract into a database on first launch.

You also can use domain-specific knowledge to encode your strings into smaller tokens. If I were encoding the NY subway system, I would notice that some strings show up a lot, like "Avenue", "Road", "Street", "East", etc. I'd probably encode those as unprintable ASCII like ^A, ^R, ^S, ^E, etc. I'd probably encode "138 Street" as two bytes (0x8A13). This of course is based on my knowledge that è (0x8a) never shows up in the NY subway stops. It's not a general solution (in Paris it might be a problem), but it can be used to highly compress data that you have special knowledge of. In a city like Washington DC, I believe their highest numbered street is 38th St, and then there's a 4-value direction. So you can encode that in two bytes, first a "numbered street" token, and then a bit field with 2 bits for the quadrant and 6 bits for the street number. This kind of thinking can potentially significantly shrink your data size.

Comment: I totally agree with you here. However, the app is meant to be able to operate offline which means all the data has to be included. Otherwise this had actually crossed my mind and would be ideal.

Comment: Yeah; I was thinking a lot more about how to better store the CSV. I think there are a lot of options. CSV really isn't that efficient. I think anything you could get out of gzip you could get better out of more clever storage solutions.

Comment: Thanks Rob for your thoughtful response. I went through the database and noticed a lot of information is being repeated, especially the headsigns, which are each stored as strings. Going over code now to eliminate that. I like your suggestion of delta time and will give that a shot. Hopefully I can get this beast to under 200MB and then gzip it and extract it to the caches folder on first run.

Comment: I see you have an idea or two about this!

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to perform some database normalization.

Look for anything that might be redundant or the same values being stored in multiple rows. You will probably need to restructure your database so these duplicate values (if any) are stored in separate tables and then referenced from their original row by means of id's.

Answer (score 0):

How big is the sqlite file compressed?  If it's satisfactorily small, the simplest thing would be to ship it compressed, then uncompress it to NSCachesDirectory.

Comment: By "compressed" I meant compressed with gzip, btw.

Comment: The file is 57.7MB when gzipped. You may be on to something here. My only concern now is how long it would typically take the phone to uncompress it.